# Diferença entre til "~" e barra "/" no prompt linux?

Tags: linux, bash

Estou iniciando uma parte mais baixo nível, onde vou programar a parte de usuários, permissões e etc.

Minha primeira dúvida é `~` e `/` no prompt ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O caractere `~` remete a pasta `home` do usuario. Por exemplo se voce digitar `cd ~` no terminal, o comando vai te levar a pasta home do usuario que esta executando esse comando.

O `/` refere-se ao ponto inicial dos arquivos do Linux. Se voce digitar `cd /` vai te levar a raiz do sistema operacional, onde ficam todas as pastas do sistema.

Comment: Tem também a opção do `cd ~outrouser` que vai para a home do `outrouser`

Comment: Rejeitei sua edição, porque a dúvida não é sobre terminais, e sobre o prompt mesmo...

Comment: Tranquilo! So achei que ficaria melhor para futuras pesquisas pois nao e comum usar o termo prompt no linux.

Answer (score 6):

Fazendo um adendo à resposta:

O caractere til `~` é um `alias` associado do diretório `home` do usuário, que também pode ser acessado através `/`, que é o ponto inicial dos diretórios e também conhecido por `root`.

`cd`, `cd ~`,`cd /home/marcelo` e `cd $HOME` são equivalentes.

Conforme esse tópico no [SOen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34196/why-was-chosen-to-represent-the-home-directory), o uso do `til` para essa associação é devido o [Lear Siegler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lear_Siegler)[ADM-3A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM-3A), que tinha a mesma tecla para `home`e `til` e levava o cursor para o início.

Layout do teclado do  Lear-Siegler ADM-3A:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No [GNU](http://www.gnu.org), há a documentação no tópico [3.5.2 Tilde Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) sobre o uso do `~`, onde você pode ver as aplicações do seu uso.

Comment: Interessante que as teclas de movimentacao do vi tambem vieram desse teclado ai!

Comment: Sim sim, há esse detalhe também.